# Word cloud stopwords are not processed

Tags: python, word-cloud

I created word cloud.
    # Python program to generate WordCloud

```
# importing all necessery modules
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from konlpy.tag import Okt

# Reads 'Youtube04-Eminem.csv' file
df = pd.read_excel(r"crawling.xlsx", encoding="UTF8")

comment_words = ''
# iterate through the csv file
for val in df.CONTENT:

    # typecaste each val to string
    val = str(val)

    okt=Okt()
    noun=okt.nouns(val)

    for i,v in enumerate(noun):
        if len(v)<2:
            noun.pop(i)

    comment_words += " ".join(noun) + " "
    count=Counter(noun)
    noun_list=count.most_common(100)

stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
stopwords.add("모든언어")
stopwords.add("모든결과")
STOPWORDS.add("모든날짜")
STOPWORDS.add('지난지난')

wordcloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=800,
                      font_path='NanumBarunGothic.otf',
                      background_color='white',
                      stopwords=stopwords,
                      min_font_size=10).generate(comment_words)

# plot the WordCloud image
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), facecolor=None)
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.savefig('word_cloud.png')
plt.show()
```

I added the word cloud stopwords to the set, but it is not reflected in the results.
Also, I made a list of stopwords and put them in, but it didn't work.
how can i do

Answer (score 0):

1-You can add stop words in a file and call that file here is the code ,It worked for me
First create the method simply copy and paste the code below

```
def load_words_from_file(path_to_file):
"""Read text file return list of words."""
sw_list = []
with open(path_to_file, 'r') as f:
    [sw_list.append(word) for line in f for word in line.split()]
return sw_list
```

2- Call this function for retrieving data from your stop words file like below

```
stop_words = load_words_from_file('stopwords.txt')

The sample file"stopwords.txt" has all words which you can type on notepad one word in one line no more than one word in a single line.
```

3-Use the variable "stop_words" in wordcloud function

```
wordcloud_statenisland = WordCloud(
background_color='white',
max_words=2000,
stopwords =stop_words,

     )
```

Hope this helps